# Can a hook be a parent of a bone?

Tags: armature, bones, hook-modifier

I have a curve with a hook and want the vertex of the curve to follow the rotation and movement of the bone. I can snap a mesh using Ctrl+P and "Snap with empty groups" and then assign a group vertex to parts of the mesh, but I can't do that with curves and hooks.
Binding an object to a parent doesn't work either.
How can I attach the curve to the bone?

[image]

Comment: Parent the empty, which is the target of the hook, to the bone, using bone or bone-relative parenting.  Or, replace the target of the hook modifier on the curve to reference the armature and bone instead of the empty.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.